# Expected number of color balls when x ball is taken out of urn at random

Tags: probability

an urn contains 4 white and 8 red balls. 3 balls are taken out at random. What is the expected number of white balls in this sample?

I did E[X] = 0*(4 C 3)/(12 C 3) + 1*(8 C 1)(4 C 2)/(12 C 3) + 2*(8 C 2)(4 C 1)/(12 C 3) + 3*(8 C 3)/(12 C 3) = 2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOIGl.jpg (picture form of work)

I got the value 2 when I plug everything into my calculator, but I don't think it's the right answer. Am I doing something wrong or is 2 the answer?

Comment: That would mean that the expected number of red balls was $1$...which is absurd.

Comment: Suggestion:  try linearity of expectation.  Or, symmetry (imagine that the $8$ red were really $4$ blue and $4$ green$, now all three expectations would clearly be equal).

Comment: my professor did a similar example and i just did the same thing. no clue why its different https://imgur.com/GjP8KLM

Comment: Your multipliers are wrong.  Your first term, $\binom 43/\binom {12}3$ corresponds to choosing ONLY white balls, so the multiplier should be $3$, not $0$.  (your expression counts the expected number of RED balls).

Comment: Suggestion:  after fixing your calculation, try it the two ways I suggested.  Both linearity and symmetry are powerful methods that often allow you to avoid heavy computation.  Granted, in this case the computation isn't particularly heavy.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the answer after fixing the calculation?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: What does the linearity of expectation or symmetry thing you were talking about then if the problem was misuse of the multipliers?

Comment: I am proposing alternate (and to my mind, better) ways of doing the problem.  Straight computation is fine, but in more complicated situations brute force computations get to be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_i$ take value $1$ if the $i$-th ball that is "touched" by the one who draws is white and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Then you are asked to find $$\mathbb E(B_1+B_2+B_3)$$

Now try to find this (as lulu suggested) by means of linear expectation.

Also you can use symmetry (why should the expectation change just by the fact the a ball is touched earlyer than another ball?).

Answer (score 0):

Each ball has  probability ${1\over12}$ to be the second ball drawn. The probability that the second ball drawn is white terefore is $4\cdot{1\over12}={1\over3}$. In other words: From the second draw we can expect ${1\over3}$ white balls. Of course the same thing is true for the first and the third draw. By linearity of expectation we can therefore expect to draw $3\cdot{1\over3}=1$ white ball in the total process.